# will Excel UDF gets calculation upon open?

Tags: c#, excel, user-defined-functions

My Excel 2007 is set to Auto Calculation Mode. 
I have two Excel files.  MyUDF (multiple cells) is used in both files. 
When I open one file in Excel, I notice no MyUDF is calculated.
But when I open the other file, all MyUDFs are calculated. 
So I am a little confused as when will a UDF be calculated upon open and when not?
MyUDF is a UDF in MyAddIn written in C#

Edit
The two files are open in the same instance of Excel.  MyUDF is not volatile.

Thanks

Edit 
I found http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b477c05a-ae0a-470c-8ad5-482ecd05944b/xll-addin-does-not-calculate-udf-when-opening-a-workbook?forum=exceldev 
It says xla will, xll, vba will not. 
hmm, this does not match what I see.

Comment: are they the same workbook, just two instances, or the same function is used in two different workbooks?  Or to put it another way, is the content the same between the two workbooks?

Comment: content are different between two workbooks. but they use the same UDF i.e. MyUDF

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.  Something like:

```
Public Function MYUDF() As Date
    Application.Volatile
    MYUDF = Now
End Function
```

will be re-calculated, however something like:

```
Public Function MYUDF() As Date
    MYUDF = Now
End Function
```

may not be re-calculated.

Comment: Thanks. MyUDF is not volatile.  I am just not sure why the same function gets calculated in one workbook upon open but not in other workbook.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to set "automatic calculation" in your workbook's Open event. Something like this *inside your `ThisWorkbook` object* (this is **important**!):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

This is just to make sure that the setting is set as you expect within your workbook to avoid relying on what calculation mode your Excel application has in its options/settings. If nothing else, at least it eliminates one possibility for why you are getting this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Excel "helpfully" remembers where the function was called from.

With he same function in both spreadsheets, Excel may simply be waiting for the other to open so it can do the calculation. Check the formula in the spreadsheet that does not recalculate, and see if it's changed to something like `'C:\MyDocs\MyOtherSpreadsheet.xlsb'!MyUDF(A1)`.

If it has, search for the full spreadsheet name (including the extra characters it uses for delimiters) and replace with nothing.

If it hasn't, set the calculation to Automatic. To force a recalculation, either select **Recalculate now** from the ribbon, press <kbd>F9</kbd>, or do a search and replace, and replace all the `=` with exactly the same.